# Cannot install @types/enzyme-adapter-react-16

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I needed to create unit tests for React application. I'm new to React, so I have troubles with setting things up.

My code is

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
```

VS code is saying "Could not find a declaration file for module 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'" and suggests to run `npm i --save-dev @types/enzyme-adapter-react-16`.
I did that and I got this error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\WORK_2\GIT\XXX\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@10.19.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^    
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\WORK_2\\GIT\\XXX\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\WORK_2\GIT\XXX\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

EDIT: I fixed this error by installing Python 2.7, but got another one:

```
npm ERR! code 7
npm ERR! path C:\WORK_2\GIT\XXX\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@10.19.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.19.0/node-v10.19.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.19.0/node-v10.19.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.19.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.19.0/win-x64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.19.0/win-x86/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.19.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.19.0/win-x64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.19.0/win-x86/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\WORK_2\\GIT\\XXX\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\WORK_2\\GIT\\XXX\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\WORK_2\\GIT\\XXX\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\XXX\\.node-gyp\\10.19.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\XXX\\.node-gyp\\10.19.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\WORK_2\\GIT\\XXX\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\XXX\\.node-gyp\\10.19.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\WORK_2\\GIT\\XXX\\node_modules\\node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\WORK_2\\GIT\\XXX\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\WORK_2\\GIT\\XXX\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\WORK_2\GIT\XXX\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
npm ERR! gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
```

Comment: There may be some Python version issue, you need to check the docs once . As in error also it's pointing Python 3.9. Maybe it's not built for 3.9, maybe for some lower version only

Comment: I installed Python 2.7, this error is gone, but there is another one.

Comment: You can update in your question

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke I was in process of doing it.

Comment: Not able to understand why it's looking for `node-sass`

Comment: Try installing `node-sass@4.14.1`

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke It is already 4.14.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it myself, I needed to run first

`npm rebuild node-sass`

And then:

`@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16`

Not sure why this happens, it seems that project uses `node-sass` for something and it causes issues.

Comment: Nice! `rebuild` is a new command for me XD